# Cannot save multiple Image using Form Data

Tags: laravel, vue.js

First of all this is the error that I get.[image]

This is my first time working with Multiple Image with other Inputs.

as you can see in my FormData Headers the picture File is an Empty Array.

[image]

But inside the console it returns a file.

[image]

my question for this one that is this good? because the picture that I'm sending is a PNG one but it only says FILE.

This is my Vue Code.

```
 <q-dialog
  v-model="uploadForm"
  transition-show="slide-up"
  transition-hide="slide-down"
  persistent
>
  <q-card style="width: 700px; max-width: 50vw;">
    <q-card-section>
      <div class="text-h6">Add Product</div>
    </q-card-section>
    <div class="q-pa-md">
      <form
        action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/createProduct"
        class="q-gutter-md"
        method="POST"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
      >
        <q-input outlined label="Product name" v-model="data.productName" />

        <q-input
          multiple="multiple"
          outlined
          type="file"
          accept="image/png,jpg/jpeg"
          @change="onFilePicked"
          ref="file"
        >
          <template v-slot:prepend>
            <q-icon name="attach_file" />
          </template>
        </q-input>
        <div>
          <div class="image-category">
            <div v-for="(image, key) in data.picture" :key="key">
              <div class="image-item">
                <img
                  class="grid"
                  :src="image.src"
                  width="300"
                  height="300"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <q-input outlined label="Description" v-model="data.description" />

        <q-input
          prefix="₱ "
          type="number"
          outlined
          label="Price"
          v-model="data.price"
        />

        <q-select
          square
          outlined
          v-model="data.category_id"
          :options="categories"
          :option-value="'id'"
          :option-label="'categoryName'"
          label="Category"
        />

        <div class="q-ma-md float-right">
          <q-btn label="Submit" color="primary" @click="createProduct" />
          <q-btn
            label="Cancel"
            color="primary"
            flat
            class="q-ml-sm"
            @click="closeCreateModal"
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div> </q-card
></q-dialog>
```

My returning Data()

```
  data: {
    picture: [],
    productName: "Grizzly Bear",
    description: "Machaba.",
    price: "260000",
    category_id: []
  },
```

my @Change in accepting multiple Images.

```
    onFilePicked(e) {
  let selectedFiles = e.target.files;
  for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
    let img = {
      src: URL.createObjectURL(selectedFiles[i]),
      file: selectedFiles[i]
    };
    this.data.picture.push(img);
    console.log(this.data.picture, "inside");
  }
  console.log(this.data.picture, "outside");
},
```

My CreatingProduct method.

```
createProduct() {
  let t = this.data;

  if (
    t.picture == "" ||
    t.productName.trim() == "" ||
    t.description.trim() == "" ||
    t.price == "" ||
    t.categories == ""
  ) {
    this.uploadForm = false;

    this.$q
      .dialog({
        title: "Incomplete Details",
        message: "Please fill up all the fields in the Product",
        persistent: true,
        color: "negative"
      })
      .onOk(() => {
        this.uploadForm = true;
      });
  } else {
    let formData = new FormData();
    const picture = JSON.stringify(this.data.picture); // returns [object, object] so I needed to do 
 //this.
    const category_id = JSON.stringify(this.data.category_id); 

    formData.append("picture", picture);
    formData.append("productName", this.data.productName);
    formData.append("description", this.data.description);
    formData.append("price", this.data.price);
    formData.append("category_id", category_id);

    let config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      }
    };

    this.$axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/createProduct", formData, config)
      .then(response => {
        this.products.unshift(response.data);
        this.uploadForm = false;
        (this.data = ""),
          this.$q.notify({
            icon: "info",
            message: "Product Added Successfully",
            color: "positive"
          });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.$q.notify({
          color: "negative",
          position: "top",
          message: "Unable to save Product",
          icon: "report_problem"
        });
      });
  }
}},
```

my Backend in laravel

```
    public function createProduct(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'productName' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'picture' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg|max:2048',
        'price' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required'
    ]);

    $product = new Product($request->input());


    if($request->hasFile('picture')){
        foreach($request->file('picture') as $file){
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path().'/uploads/',$name);
            $product->picture = $name;
        }
    }

    $product->save();

    return response()->json($product);

}
```

Can anyone explain to me what is wrong? I made my research and it doesn't work. and also how do you edit a multiple Image? How would you select a specific image in the Index to make that one being edit.

this is my first time working with Quasar + Laravel in creating a Product with Multiple Image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing some things wrong, if you use a framework try to use it as it was intended either the validations or components they have, I detail an example

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#q-app',
    data: function() {
        return {
            uploadForm: true,
            data: {
                picture: [],
                productName: "Grizzly Bear",
                description: "Machaba.",
                price: "260000",
                category_id: null
            },
            categories: [
                { id: 1, categoryName: 'categoria 1' }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        createProduct() {
            this.$q.loading.show()
            let formData = new FormData()

            formData.append("picture", this.data.picture);
            formData.append("productName", this.data.productName);
            formData.append("description", this.data.description);
            formData.append("price", this.data.price);
            formData.append("category_id", this.data.category_id.id);

            axios.post('http://localhost:8000/', formData, {
                'headers': {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;'
                }
            }).then((response) => {
                alert(response)
            }).catch(error => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('error', error)
                }
            }).finally(() => {
                this.$q.loading.hide()
            })
        },
        closeCreateModal() {
            alert('close')
        },
    }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@quasar/extras/material-icons/material-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar/dist/quasar.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar/dist/quasar.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="q-app">
  <q-dialog v-model="uploadForm"
            transition-show="slide-up"
            transition-hide="slide-down"
            persistent>
    <q-card style="width: 700px; max-width: 50vw;">
      <q-card-section>
        <div class="text-h6">Add Product</div>
      </q-card-section>
      <q-card-section class="q-pt-none">
        <div class="q-pa-md">
          <q-form @submit="createProduct"
                  class="q-gutter-md">
              <q-input outlined
                       label="Product name"
                       v-model="data.productName"
                       :rules="[val => !!val || 'Field is required']"></q-input>

              <q-file multiple outlined v-model="data.picture" label="Outlined" accept="image/png,jpg/jpeg"
:rules="[val => !!val || 'Field is required']">
                <template v-slot:prepend>
                <q-icon name="attach_file" ></q-icon>
                </template>
              </q-file>
              <q-input outlined
                       label="Description"
                       v-model="data.description"
                       :rules="[val => !!val || 'Field is required']"></q-input>
              <q-input prefix="₱ "
                       type="number"
                       outlined
                       label="Price"
                       v-model="data.price"
                       :rules="[val => !!val || 'Field is required']"></q-input>
              <q-select square
                        outlined
                        v-model="data.category_id"
                        :options="categories"
                        option-value="id"
                        option-label="categoryName"
                        label="Category"
                        :rules="[val => !!val || 'Field is required']"
                        ></q-select>
              <div>
                <q-btn label="Submit"
                       color="primary"
                       type="submit"></q-btn>
                <q-btn label="Cancel"
                       @click="closeCreateModal"
                       flat class="q-ml-sm"></q-btn>
            </div>
          </q-form>
        </div>
      </q-card-section>
    </q-card>
  </q-dialog>
</div>
```

if you see the log the "picture" attribute has an array of Object File

[image]

I leave the backend processing (laravel) at your discretion

I think it would be easier if you share a link with your problem for future reference

https://jsfiddle.net/idkc/L8xn0puq/52/